# How to replace or remove any specific CSS property with css file for IE8 and lower only using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

This is css code which I only want for **IE8 and lower**

```
background: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); / IE6-8 */
```

But if user is on **IE9** I either want to remove this propert from CSS file or I want to replace with `filter:none`

is it possible using javascript, jquery? I know I can do with seperate style sheet for IE but just curious if it's possible with javascript.

**Edit:**

Is it possible like in javascript or jquery

```
// If browser is IE9
```

then replace

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(values)`

to `filter:none`

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to put an "IE" class on your HTML element using conditional code... I think I got this originally from the HTML5 boilerplate http://html5boilerplate.com/

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

.bg-gradient {background: filter: 0, #999}

.ie .bg-gradient {  
    background: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); / IE6-8 */
}
```

Then simply use add and remove class to remove the 'element' class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.element').addClass('bg-gradient');
})
```

Filter won't be rendered by non IE browsers so adding it or removing for all browsers *except* IE 6-8 will have the same effect as doing it just for IE9. Also I believe that ie9 supports multiple background properties so the other browsers should skip over the first comma separated value-- in theory-- I haven't tested it. If not, just use regular css2 syntax:

```
.bg-gradient {background: filter: 0}
```

Comment: What i want to do is if user open webpage on IE9 then a javascript code should detect `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient*` in css and replace to `filter:none`

Comment: so you want to parse a css file with javascript?

Comment: I would say this is the answer, but for a few glaring details.  "Less than IE9" is a query that will never have to be amended.  He should just go with that instead of assuming that "IE9" will suffice.  Also, waiting for document.ready is asking for flicker.  He would be much better off putting the <script> tag immediately after the <body> tag and adding the CSS class to the body instead of HTML will avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is **"possible"** in JavaScript. But it needs to be done both at the sever-side as well as client-side.

On the client-side, you need to detect if it is a IE9 and then send a request to the server for a script (server-side JavaScript) that parses the CSS files and replaces all occurrences of the filter properties and set it to `filter:none` and then serve the modified CSS file to the client.

PS: *This, IMHO, would be the worst thing that you can ever do and I don't recommend it. This is just to answer your curious question if this is "possible in JavaScript".*

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {
         $("#element").css("filter", "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 );")
    }
})
```

Comment: I want to do for all not specific element or gradient.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional comments and add a css file for IE8 and lower
[here is a tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

EDIT: use [jquery's browser check](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) and apply the css with javascript
with `jQuery.browser.version` you can get the version

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are different answers out here but personally I will advise the following approach.

Have two CSS classes - one containing styling for IE9 and the other containing styling for all the other browsers.

As mentioned in one of the answers above, use jQuery.browser API to determine the browser type.
I will advise that you add this string say "msie9" or "msie8" as a class to "body" or "html" element.

Once this is done, your styling for IE9 will be

body.msie9 .ie9specificclass{
}

For others, it will be

.specificClass{
}

This will be a clean approach.